# Can I apply for a new Schengen visa before my current multiple entry visa expires?

Tags: visas, schengen, france, south-african-citizens, long-stay-visas

Hoping someone can help me figure out what to do.

I've got a South African passport with a 90 days multiple entry Italian Schengen visa, expiring 14-03-2016. I'm currently in France till mid November (leaving a valid 45 days early) before going back home for a few months. I would like to then leave South Africa at the end of February 2016 to spend a full 3 months in France.

When home can I apply for a new 3 month French Schengen visa before my current one expires?

Answer (score 1):

You can apply up to 3 months before February 2016 so mid-November should be fine. But you don't need to apply for a 3-month French visa, what France is supposed to do is issue a visa starting on the 15th of March to cover the time after the expiration of your Italian visa.